# Terraform null_resource trigger when file missing

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am using `null_resource` provisioner to copy source files into `build` folder and run package installation. Then I use `archive_file` to create a `zip` that is used for a serverless function deployment. The current trigger is a `output_sha` of a zip file I create only for the purpose of detecting a change to the source. All works well except when the copy of source gets deleted from the `build` folder. At that point Terraform assumes that the source has not changed, the `null_resource` is not replaced and therefore no files end up in the `build` folder.

Is there a way to to trigger the `null_resource` when the file is missing as well when the source changes?

Terraform version `1.2.8`

Here is a sample of what is happening:

```
data "archive_file" "change_check" {
  type = "zip"

  source_dir  = local.src_dir
  output_path = "${local.change_check_path}/${var.lambda_name}.zip"
}

resource "null_resource" "dependencies" {
  triggers = {
    src_hash = data.archive_file.change_check.output_sha
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      rm -rf ${local.build_dir};
      cp -R ${local.src_dir} ${local.build_dir};
    EOT
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "pip install -r ${local.build_dir}/requirements.txt -t ${local.build_dir}/python --upgrade"
  }
}
```

Comment: If your `local.src_dir` is missing, then you should get errors. So its not clear how exactly your code even works when "copy of source gets deleted" and there is nothing to zip.

Comment: ? src_dir is not missing. build_dir can be missing if there is no change in src but build directory gets removed (or runs on different CI/CD node with shared state?) prior to plan or apply. No reason for src_dir to be missing.